# File completion when mapping commands in VIM

Tags: ruby, vim, tdd, terminal, vi

I often create a **temporary mapping** to do something on a particular file.

Typical example is this:

```
:map <leader>f :w<cr>:! bundle exec cucumber features/account/sign_in.feature:41<cr>
```

I want the file `features/account/sign_in.feature` to be autocompleted from the current directory.

This should simply save the current file and shell out on `<leader>f` to run the command.

It allows me to easily **work on a piece of code not thinking about jumping** to a particular file and run it.

The problem is that creating such a binding is cumbersome and **error prone**.

VIM doesn't allow **completing the file name when mapping**. Also using `%` is totally different ( I want to map to a file **statically**).

What is a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry it isn't clear, at all, what filename you want to complete. Where does `:41` come from anyway?

Comment: I've updated the question. I want to autocomplete `features/account/sign_in.feature`. The 41 doesn't matter (it's the line number in the file).

Comment: And _where_ do you want to 'complete' it from (the word _completion_ suggests that you have a part, and the rest must be _appended automatically_; Filename completion usually implies looking at possible filenames and selecting the name of an existing, accessible file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allthough I think your question should be made a lot clearer, here are some hints:

```
:nnoremap <leader>f :w<bar>!exec "bundle exec cucumber " . expand('%') . ":" . line('.')<CR>
```

Will correctly save and insert current filename/line number in the command

Also, you will want to know about the `autowrite` option:

```
:se autowrite
```

Lastly, I usually employ `makeprg` for this kind of purpose:

```
:let &makeprg="bundle exec cucumber %"
```

This has the added benefit of working with quickfix commands (`:copen`, `:colder`, `:cnewer`) and (given a correct `makef`) also jumping to error lines

Comment: Good to know about `autowrite`. Thanks. Can you please expand a bit more on how to use `makeprg` here?

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak: Yup, I already showed how to set it. I suggest you try it by doing `:make|copen` (and `:help quickfix` for complete documentation on all quickfix commands)

Comment: Why do I need to type `:make|copen` if just pressing `<leader>f` is much faster? I just want to have a shortcut for the command (which is often different, it's not a compiler or similar). The mapping of that command is just error-prone.

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak: You answered your own question. Mapping `:nnoremap <leader>f :make<CR>` is _less errorprone_. Plus, it has quickfix semantics. Besides, no one said you **have to**, it is just what I use, and I thought I'd mention it? (_Does the first mapping not do what you want? I'd expect it does_)

Comment: The first mapping should do the job indeed. As for `:noremap <leader>f :make<CR>` - I still need to `:let &makegrp` before that; which seems to take longer than doing it in one command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer but if I were you I'd use cabbr:

```
:cabbr fas features/account/sign_in.features:
```

Or something like that. It's not autocomplete, but it sure does reduce the number of keystrokes you need.

Another alternative is to create a function mapped from a user command that accepts an argument that creates the mapping. If I remember it correctly you can customize the user command completion so that might work.

Update: yes you can customize user command. See `:help user-command`

Something like this should get you started:

```
command -complete=file_in_path -nargs=1 Map call CreateMap(expand('<args>'))

function CreateMap(filename)
    exec 'map <leader>f :w<cr>:! bundle exec cucumber ' . a:filename . ':41<cr>'
endfun
```

Once you do that, ensure that you 'path' setting includes the current directory ".", or if you want to make it search recursively "./**". Then you can use the `Map` user command like this:

```
:Map fea<tab>ac<tab>
```